# if not (target.size() == input.size()): AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'size' I'm getting this error

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to perform semantic segmentation using deeplab v3 architecture in pytorch using transfer learning. And this is the error. I'm using ISIC 2017 skin legion dataset and have converted the images and labels to 160 by 240. Can anybody please help me with this problem.

**main.py**

```
train function

def train_fn(loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler ):
loop = tqdm(loader)

for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(loop):
    data= data.to(device= DEVICE).float()
    targets= targets.float().unsqueeze(1).to(device =  DEVICE)
           #forward


    with torch.cuda.amp.autocast():
        predictions= model(data)
        loss= loss_fn(predictions, targets)

    #backward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    scaler.scale(loss).backward()
    scaler.step(optimizer)
    scaler.update()


    #update tqdm loop
    loop.set_postfix(loss= loss.item())
```

**It's called using**

```
model = DeepLabv3().to(DEVICE)
loss_fn = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr= LEARNING_RATE)
scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler()
for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCH):
    train_fn(train_loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler)
    # save model
    checkpoint = {
        "state_dict": model.state_dict(),
        "optimizer":optimizer.state_dict(),
    }
    save_checkpoint(checkpoint)

    #check accuracy
    check_accuracy(test_loader, model, device=DEVICE)

    # print some examples to a folder
    save_predictions_as_imgs(
        test_loader, model, folder="saved_images/", device=DEVICE
    )


def DeepLabv3(outputchannels=1):

model = models.segmentation.deeplabv3_resnet101(pretrained=True,
                                                progress=True)
model.classifier = DeepLabHead(2048, outputchannels)
# Set the model in training mode
model.train()
#print(model)
return model

DeepLabv3()
```

**error**

```
    File "main.py", line 94, in <module>
    train_fn(train_loader, model, optimizer, loss_fn, scaler)
  File "main.py", line 75, in train_fn
    loss= loss_fn(predictions, targets)
  File "C:\Users\anush\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\anush\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 707, in forward
    reduction=self.reduction)
  File "C:\Users\anush\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2979, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
    if not (target.size() == input.size()):
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'size'
```

Comment: Share the ful stacktract, so we know the line that raise the error in your code

Comment: [eidt] your post and add it properly

Comment: done. I hope it's fine now

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem today when using the Deeplab. I think the main reason is that the output from deeplab is 'class collections.OrderedDict'. It can not compare with tensor.
The structure is like that:

```
OrderedDict([('out', tensor([[[[-1.7589, -1.7589, -1.7589,  ..., -1.3775, -1.3775, -1.3775],
          [-1.7589, -1.7589, -1.7589,  ..., -1.3775, -1.3775, -1.3775],
          [-1.7589, -1.7589, -1.7589,  ..., -1.3775, -1.3775, -1.3775],
          ...,
          [-1.9924, -1.9924, -1.9924,  ..., -2.2682, -2.2682, -2.2682],
          [-1.9924, -1.9924, -1.9924,  ..., -2.2682, -2.2682, -2.2682],
          [-1.9924, -1.9924, -1.9924,  ..., -2.2682, -2.2682, -2.2682]]],


        [[[-1.8675, -1.8675, -1.8675,  ..., -2.0556, -2.0556, -2.0556],
          [-1.8675, -1.8675, -1.8675,  ..., -2.0556, -2.0556, -2.0556],
          [-1.8675, -1.8675, -1.8675,  ..., -2.0556, -2.0556, -2.0556],
          ...,
          [-2.1846, -2.1846, -2.1846,  ..., -2.0779, -2.0779, -2.0779],
          [-2.1846, -2.1846, -2.1846,  ..., -2.0779, -2.0779, -2.0779],
          [-2.1846, -2.1846, -2.1846,  ..., -2.0779, -2.0779, -2.0779]]],


        [[[-1.9245, -1.9245, -1.9245,  ..., -1.9551, -1.9551, -1.9551],
          [-1.9245, -1.9245, -1.9245,  ..., -1.9551, -1.9551, -1.9551],
          [-1.9245, -1.9245, -1.9245,  ..., -1.9551, -1.9551, -1.9551],
          ...,
          [-2.1327, -2.1327, -2.1327,  ..., -2.1104, -2.1104, -2.1104],
          [-2.1327, -2.1327, -2.1327,  ..., -2.1104, -2.1104, -2.1104],
          [-2.1327, -2.1327, -2.1327,  ..., -2.1104, -2.1104, -2.1104]]],


        [[[-1.8399, -1.8399, -1.8399,  ..., -1.6801, -1.6801, -1.6801],
          [-1.8399, -1.8399, -1.8399,  ..., -1.6801, -1.6801, -1.6801],
          [-1.8399, -1.8399, -1.8399,  ..., -1.6801, -1.6801, -1.6801],
          ...,
          [-1.9659, -1.9659, -1.9659,  ..., -1.8788, -1.8788, -1.8788],
          [-1.9659, -1.9659, -1.9659,  ..., -1.8788, -1.8788, -1.8788],
          [-1.9659, -1.9659, -1.9659,  ..., -1.8788, -1.8788, -1.8788]]]],
       device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<UpsampleBilinear2DBackward1>))])
```

As you can see, the tensor result is in this OrderedDict.

Thus, what you need to do is just change the

```py
loss= loss_fn(predictions, targets)
```

to

```py
loss= loss_fn(predictions['out'], targets)
```